# When I run wpf project application, combobox is not responding to the mouse click and drop down list is not appearing

Tags: wpf

I am working on wpf application and I am kinda new.

I have added combobox to the stackpanel where first child is menu and second child combobox.

Look at the code below:

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel>
        <Menu Background="Chocolate" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="File"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Edit"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="View"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Help"></MenuItem>
        </Menu>
            <ComboBox Width="100" Height="30" Loaded="Cbox_Load" Margin="30" SelectionChanged="Cbox_Changed_event">

            </ComboBox>


        </StackPanel>
<ScrollViewer>
------rest of controls---
</ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And the code to load data into combobox and handle selection change is as below:

```
private void Cbox_Changed_event(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        //    string text = (e.AddedItems[0] as ComboBoxItem).Content as string;
        }
        private void Cbox_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> zoomList = new List<string>();
            zoomList.Add("100");
            zoomList.Add("200");
            zoomList.Add("300");
            zoomList.Add("400");

            var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
            comboBox.ItemsSource = zoomList;
            comboBox.Focusable = true;
        }
```

The problem:When run the project, I am unable to click on the combobox to select a combobox item. The combobox appears as if disabled

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two controls StackPanel and ScrollViewer in the same cell: row="0", column="0". Put them to different cells.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>       
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <Menu Background="Chocolate" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="File"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Edit"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="View"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Help"></MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <ComboBox Width="100" Height="30" Loaded="Cbox_Load" Margin="30" SelectionChanged="Cbox_Changed_event">
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">    
            <!-- ... -->
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```